# Calculate and display the percentage of values in the array

Tags: java, arrays, percentage

This are my requirements:

1. Read in an integer from the user (n)
2. Declare an array of floating point numbers of size n
3. Fill in this array with random floating point numbers between 0 and 100.
4. Calculate and display the percentage of values in the array that are at least 70

I dont know how to do the last part.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 *
 */
public class Mo {

    /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.print("please enter a number: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    float[] values;
    values = new float[n];

    int[] counters;
    counters = new int[n];

    Random r = new Random();

    for(int i=0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = r.nextInt(100);
        System.out.print(values[i] + " " );

    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count numbers of values that are <70 then divide this count by total count
if (values[i] >= 70 ) 
  count++;

outside the for

count/values.length*100

Comment: thanks @MichaelT, i was thinking somethign like if (values[i] >= 70 )
                counters = values[i] / values.length; but i get some weird number can you give give me an idea or example? as you can see I'm new at this. Thanks.